# Image with Transparency Overlay Misaligned when background image is applied

Tags: android, layout, background, alignment, overlay

I'm trying to create an image with a transparency overlay at the bottom, aligned the right and left side of the image. So far I have been able to do this with the following layout

```
          <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="310px"
            android:layout_height="300px"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="300px"
                android:layout_height="300px"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/color_test_pattern" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/overlay"
                android:layout_width="300px"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#99000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="This is A Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Which nicely gives me:

[image]

This works fine and produces my overlay, but I run into issue when I try and set a background  shadow for the image, the overlay doesn't align correctly and over runs the bottom and the right sides of the image.

The only difference to the above layout is the imageView now the background set to a shadow

```
<ImageView  
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="300px" 
android:layout_height="300px" 
android:src="@drawable/color_test_pattern"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
/>
```

This is the result

[image]

Any ideas how to remedy?

Comment: Have you tried using ImageView's src attribute instead of background? You can also keep the aspect ratio using adjustViewBounds="true" with src

Comment: Hmmm not quite sure what you mean 'use ImageView's src attribute instead of background', I need to set the src to the drawable image (in this example `color_test_pattern`) for it to display the picture.  Tried adding `adjustViewBounds="true"` to the imageView but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: adjustViewBounds doesn't work for the background attribute. Instead, set the image by: android:src="@drawable/shadow" instead of the background

Comment: That didn't work, I swapped the scr image and the background image over to give me `<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="300px" 
    android:layout_height="300px" 
    android:src="@drawable/shadow"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:background="@drawable/color_test_pattern"
    />`  The shadow image file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw6tbZv6Cc-GekYzUV9wZ2dLTkU/edit?usp=sharing[link]  This is

Comment: The shadow image is of size 26px by 36px not sure how its able to stretch around larger images. If I use the shadow as the main image it is just put in the centre of the main image.

Comment: Remove the android:background attribute

Comment: I need the shadow to be displayed under the image, if I do as you suggest there is no image just a shadow.